# Is gradle's emmaPlugin still working?

Tags: gradle, emma

https://github.com/breskeby/gradleplugins/tree/master/emmaPlugin

I can't get it to work with gradle 1.7 with the current documentation.

Comment: The sample build.gradle doesn't work with gradle 1.9 either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh finally:

```
apply from:'http://github.com/breskeby/gradleplugins/raw/master/emmaPlugin/emma.gradle'
```

Didn't work - had to download it and put it locally. So:

```
apply from: 'emma.gradle'
```

Works :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the given github.com link redirects to raw.githubusercontent.com

try

`apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/breskeby/gradleplugins/master/emmaPlugin/emma.gradle'`